# PyMySQL with Python 3.5 - selecting into pandas dataframe with the LIKE clause fails due to escape characters?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, python-3.5

I am using PyMySQL to fetch some data from the MySQL DB into pandas dataframe. I need to run a select with the LIKE clause, but seems like PyMySQL does something weird with the select statement and doesn't like when one has % in the query:

```
#connection to MySQL
engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://user:password@localhost:1234/mydb', echo=False)
#get descriptions we want
decriptions = pd.read_sql(sql=r"select content from listings where content not like '%The Estimate%'", con = engine)
```

I get error:

```
ValueError: unsupported format character 'T' (0x54) at index 54
```

Any advice on how to get around this?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I already tried it - no change

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using  `%%`

```
decriptions = pd.read_sql(sql=r"select content 
         from listings where content not like '%%The Estimate%'", con = engine)
```

Comment: Thank you sir. Can you provide any background on why/what is happening?

Comment: because pyton use % for parameter ..  so you need  to add the % for like

Comment: I get it, but the point is that I use SQLAlchemy for connection and when I connect to MSSQL server this query works fine without %% usage. So I just tried to understand why it is needed for MmySQL via PyMySQL lib

Comment: i can't help your for this difference between the two DB Driver